# How to use Waterfall process in Nodejs using LUIS

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-language-understanding, azure-bot-service

I have LUIS app created, with 1 intent(Order Pizza) and 9 entities(Order,Kind, Signature, Size, Toppings, address, Time, Duration, Range).

I need to create a bot in Azure Bot Framework. I'm unable to understand and use the waterfall for all the entities. Please let me know how to go about it

Code :

```
 dialog.matches('OrderPizza', [
 function (session, args, next) {

   var order = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'order');
   var kind = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'Kind');
   session.dialogData.intentScore = args.score;

   if (!order) {
       builder.Prompts.text(session, 'welcome please order pizza');
   } else {
       session.dialogData.order = order;
       next();
   }
 },
 function (session, results) {
   var order = session.dialogData.order;
   if (results.response) {
       session.send('what kind?');
   }else{
       session.send(`we don't have that kind of pizza`);
   }
 }

    ]);
```

How to go further for other entities?

Comment: Try [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/nodejs/bot-builder-nodejs-dialog-manage-conversation)

Comment: Thanks, I tried. But can only write 2 functions. After which its not executing

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by only being able to write 2 functions; but if you're trying to call LUIS inside of your dialog you can follow this [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2741#issuecomment-301888868). You'll call a LuisRecognizer inside your waterfall step on `session.message.text`. The snippet from the example is below:

```
builder.LuisRecognizer.recognize(session.message.text, '<model url>', function (err, intents, entities) {
   if (entities) {
     var entity = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(entities, 'TYPE');
     // do something with entity...
   }
});
```

This would allow you to call LUIS inside a waterfall for recognizing your user's messages.

Regarding your code there is a number of issues:

```
// Original Code
dialog.matches('OrderPizza', [
  function (session, args, next) {
   var order = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'order');
   var kind = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'Kind');
   session.dialogData.intentScore = args.score;

   if (!order) { // What about kind?
       builder.Prompts.text(session, 'welcome please order pizza');
   } else {
       session.dialogData.order = order; // What about kind?
       next();
   }
 },
 function (session, results) {
   var order = session.dialogData.order;
   if (results.response) {
       session.send('what kind?');
   }else{
       session.send(`we don't have that kind of pizza`);
   }
 }
]);
```

In your first waterfall step you're not saving the `"Kind"` entity to your dialogData.

```
function (session, args, next) {
  var order = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'order');
  var kind = builder.EntityRecognizer.findEntity(args.entities, 'Kind');
  session.dialogData.intentScore = args.score;

  if (kind) {
    session.dialogData.kind = kind;
  }

  if (!order) {
    builder.Prompts.text(session, 'welcome please order pizza');
  } else {
     session.dialogData.order = order;
     next();
  }
}
```

In your second waterfall step you are not calling `next`, nor are you sending a `Prompt` to the user, which results in you being stuck after two functions.

```
function (session, results, next) {
  var order = session.dialogData.order ? session.dialogData.order : results.response;
  var kind = session.dialogData.kind;

  if (results.response && !kind) {
    builder.Prompts.text(session, 'what kind?');
  } else {
    session.send('we don\'t have that kind of pizza');
    next();
  }
}
```